# Retrieving bitcoin from old seed

Tags: wallet-recovery

In January 2016 I bought a bitcoin but I don't remember what program I used. I used the seed code and now I entered a wallet. However, it is empty. And it also says there haven't been any transactions ever. Did I enter a wrong seed or someone else's seed? Or can the history be removed? Or does it matter in which program I use the seed? Or does it have to do with the halving? Please help me to recover my BTC.

Comment: so this question is not suitable for this forum because it requires back and forth diagnoses. i suggest you create a thread on bitcointalk.org forum or the bitcoin beginners subreddit. be sure to mention what software you've tried restoring from seed in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is a 'seed phrase' independent of the type of wallet?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/96437/is-a-seed-phrase-independent-of-the-type-of-wallet)

Comment: If that was a BIP39 mnemonic phrase, the upcoming new version of Electrum will provide a scanning/probing feature for wallet recovery purposes: https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/issues/6155

Answer (score 0):

Discovering which wallet this was generated from may be important. Over the years different words and derived paths have been used by different software.

A good place to start is to look through https://walletsrecovery.org/ which may help jog your memory and a start on the recovery process.